# Getting command output parameter

Tags: command-line, vbscript

I run a command and get the required output but from this output data I need to get the required parameter value. problem is required parameter name appears in 2 places, so I code which I have returns always 2nd instance parameter value in place of 1st occurrence. I don't know in VBScript if we can do exact match .

Command output is :

```
Product Name: DellRack81
Part Number: QAWSX
System Board Spare Part Number: 01032-001
```

from the above output, I wanted to get the "Part Number:" value but the code returns value of "System Board Spare Part Number".

Result getting now is :

```
Product Name    Part Number   System Board Spare Part Number
DellRack81      01032-001     01032-001
```

What i'm trying for is:

```
Product Name    Part Number   System Board Spare Part Number
DellRack81      QAWSX         01032-001
```

Comment: I get an error when I run this (51, 37) Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Expected end of statement

Answer (score 0):

Your naive condition

```
InStr(1,StrTest,"Part Number")  > 0
```

is true for both "Part Number" and "System Board Spare Part Number", so `StrPNo` is set twice. Change the conditions to check for position **1**.

**Update:**

```
Option Explicit

Dim a : a = Split("Product Name: DellRack81|Part Number: QAWSX|System Board Spare Part Number: 01032-001", "|")
ReDim b(2)
Dim s
For Each s In a
    WScript.Echo s
    If InStr(1, s,"Product Name:") = 1 Then b(0) = UCase(Trim(Mid(s,(InStr(1,s,":",1)+2))))
    If InStr(1, s,"Part Number:") = 1 Then b(1) = UCase(Trim(Mid(s,(InStr(1,s,":",1)+2))))
    If InStr(1, s,"System Board Spare Part Number:") = 1 Then b(2) = UCase(Trim(Mid(s,(InStr(1,s,":",1)+2))))
Next
WScript.Echo Join(b, vbCrLf)
```

output:

```
cscript 39146660.vbs
Product Name: DellRack81
Part Number: QAWSX
System Board Spare Part Number: 01032-001
DELLRACK81
QAWSX
01032-001
```

(you shouldn't use this strategy at work)

Comment: No luck Ekkehard. I tried your suggestion but I still same output. InStr(1,StrTest,"Part Number")  > 1

Comment: It's not a question of luck.

Comment: Sorry Ekkehard, I still couldn't. Can you please explain/show where I need to make changes look for position 1 since am not able to figure it out.

Comment: @Prime, it is not `>1`. The position of "Part Number:" must be `=1`, So try this instead: `InStr(1,StrTest,"Part Number") = 1`

Comment: @Victor, I tried with =1 but still didn't get the required value for first Part Number.

Comment: @Victor, yes I did try Ekkehard update, still not getting the required output. I have updated my original post with full vbs code. hope can find the issue in the code which I can't figure it out...

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner  did you check my new post is that what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set Sh = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
cmdLine = '" type her your command line you want to execute"    
Set oEx = Sh.Exec(cmdLine)
Set oSOut = oEx.StdOut
Do While Not oSOut.AtEndOfStream
    Line = oSOut.ReadLine
    If InStr (1,Line,"Part Number:",1) > 0 Then
      MsgBox Line
      Exit Do 
    End If 
Loop
```

This script will execute the command line you add there in **`cmdline`** variable   .

in the first **`Part Number:`** it will display the line and then will exit the loop . it will not display the second line of part number.

OR

```
Set Sh = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
cmdLine = '" type her your command line you want to execute"    
Set oEx = Sh.Exec(cmdLine)
Set oSOut = oEx.StdOut
Do While Not oSOut.AtEndOfStream
    Line = oSOut.ReadLine

    If StrComp(Left(Line,12),"Part Number:",1) = 0 Then
    MsgBox Line
    End If 
Loop
```

This code will go through all line of command line result but it will only display the first part Number and ignore the other in the list.no need to exit the do loop this time.

Comment: But the HULK *wants* the 01032-001 value for the "System Board Spare Part Number:" key. Look at the code, that the HULK removed some revisions ago.

Comment: what i understand from what he write he want this "Part Number: QAWSX" line he didnot  want the second one.

Comment: and no any problem if he want  the second one he will just replace in first script "Part Number:" in condition statement with "system board spare part number:" .and in the second script he will replace in condition statement  left (line,12) with  Mid(line,20,12)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the three item **`Product Name`** and  **`Part Number`** and  **`System Board Spare Part Number`**

```
Set Sh = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
cmdLine =  '" type her your command line you want to execute"    
Set oEx = Sh.Exec(cmdLine)
Set oSOut = oEx.StdOut

txt=""
myArray=Array("Product Name","Part Number","System Board Spare Part Number")
Do While Not oSOut.AtEndOfStream
    Line = oSOut.ReadLine
For i=0 To  UBound(myArray)
    If InStr (1,Line,myArray(i),1) > 0 Then
    txt= Line&vbCrLf&txt
    End If 
    Next 
Loop
MsgBox txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the three item **`Product Name`** and  **`Part Number`** and  **`System Board Spare Part Number`**  use this way its stronger than other one.

```
Set Sh = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
cmdLine = '" type her your command line you want to execute"    
Set oEx = Sh.Exec(cmdLine)
Set oSOut = oEx.StdOut

txt=""
myArray=Array("Product Name","Part Number","System Board Spare Part Number")
Do  Until oSOut.AtEndOfStream
    Line = oSOut.ReadLine   
For i=0  To  UBound(myArray)
A=myArray(i)
L=Len(A)
LF=Left(Trim(Line),L)
 If StrComp(LF,A,1) = 0 Then
    txt= trim(Line) & vbCrLf & txt 
    End If 
 Next
Loop
  MsgBox txt
```